# ARM template for Azure Function with V2 Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have been using an ARM template to deploy an Azure Function with Azure Ad b2c authentication using V1 authentication.

```json
    "resources": [{
        "name": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '/authsettings')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "enabled": true,
          "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
          "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
          "clientSecret":"[parameters('b2cClientSecret')]",
          "clientId": "[parameters('b2cClientId')]",
          "issuer": "[parameters('b2cMetadataDocumentUrl')]"
        }
      }]
```

Everything has been working fine until I started getting messages to **upgrade from the classic authentication experience** in the Azure Portal.

[image]

Since getting this message deployments have failed with the message below

```
##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
##[error]Details:
##[error]undefined: Cannot execute the request for site app-fun-my-af because the site is running on auth version v2.
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
Finishing: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment
```

I have fixed this by moving to the [V2 template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-authsettingsv2?tabs=json) as below and using an app setting for the client secret:

```json
"resources": [
       {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '/authsettingsV2')]",
        "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "globalValidation": {            
            "requireAuthentication": true,
            "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage"
          },
          "login": {
            "tokenStore": {
              "tokenStoreEnabled": true
            }
          },   
          "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
            "clientSecretSettingName":"B2C_CLIENT_SECRET",
            "clientId": "[parameters('b2cClientId')]",
            "issuer": "[parameters('b2cMetadataDocumentUrl')]"
          }          
        }        
      }
      ]
```

This doesn't error and adds authentication but does not correctly add the Identity Provider. Does anyone have an example of a working template with authsettingV2 for a custom provider they could share to give me an idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `customOpenIdConnectProviders` let you add multiple providers so you need to give it a name to the custom provider. Something like that should work:

```json
{
  ...
  "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
    // name of the provider (could be anything)
    "b2c": {
      "registration": {
        "clientCredential": {
          "clientSecretSettingName": "B2C_CLIENT_SECRET"
        },
        "clientId": "[parameters('b2cClientId')]",
        "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
          "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "[parameters('b2cMetadataDocumentUrl')]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

you could also configure it manually from the portal then query the ARM API to get the configuration:

```
az rest --method get `
  --uri /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function-app-name>/config/authsettingsV2?api-version=2022-03-01
```

Full config:

```json
{
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '/authsettingsV2')]",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appName'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "globalValidation": {
      "requireAuthentication": true,
      "unauthenticatedClientAction": "Return401"
    },
    "httpSettings": {
      "forwardProxy": {
        "convention": "NoProxy"
      },
      "requireHttps": true,
      "routes": {
        "apiPrefix": "/.auth"
      }
    },
    "identityProviders": {
      "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
        "b2c": {
          "registration": {
            "clientCredential": {
              "clientSecretSettingName": "B2C_CLIENT_SECRET"
            },
            "clientId": "[parameters('b2cClientId')]",
            "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
              "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "[parameters('b2cMetadataDocumentUrl')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "login": {
      "cookieExpiration": {
        "convention": "FixedTime",
        "timeToExpiration": "08:00:00"
      },
      "nonce": {
        "nonceExpirationInterval": "00:05:00",
        "validateNonce": true
      },
      "preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins": false,
      "routes": {},
      "tokenStore": {
        "azureBlobStorage": {},
        "enabled": true,
        "fileSystem": {},
        "tokenRefreshExtensionHours": 72.0
      }
    },
    "platform": {
      "enabled": true,
      "runtimeVersion": "~1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am still having problems with adding the provider but this set me in the right direction. I will leave this open for now until I have a successful deployment and then update the example and mark this as the answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to help you figure out the exact configuration that you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I have added the full config for anyone else to use as a reference.