# how to add Identity provider to app service by bicep script?

Tags: azure, identity, azure-resource-manager, azure-appservice, azure-bicep

I need to create app registration and then add it as Identity provider to app service programmatically (by bicep).

It's possible [to create app registration using  Deployment Scripts](https://reginbald.medium.com/creating-app-registration-with-arm-bicep-b1d48a287abb).

But how I can add it to app service?

For creating app service we use [Microsoft.Web sites 2020-12-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

But I don't see any property for Identity provider.

We have property identity, but it's for [ManagedServiceIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#managedserviceidentity).

Maybe [Microsoft.Web sites/config 'authsettings'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-authsettings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)?

But:

> The sites/config resource type can be deployed to: Resource groups.

So, question is: is it possible to add Identity provider by bicep or I should do it manually?

Comment: It is possible to add Identity Provider by bicep.Please refer [identityProviders for bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2021-08-01/service/identityproviders?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Comment: okay, I can create identity provider, but how to add it to app service?

Comment: you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73147492/4167200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `authsettingsV2`. Full documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-authsettingsv2?tabs=json&pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

```bicep
param webappname string

resource webapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name:webappname
}

resource authsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webapp
  name: 'authsettingsV2'
  properties:{
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also refer to a similar post: [ARM template for Azure Function with V2 Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147492/arm-template-for-azure-function-with-v2-authentication).